# Offline maintenance message not legible on Christianity.SE

Tags: bug, design, offline

The offline maintenance message is not easily read on Christianity.SE because it's white text on an almost white background.

[image: Screenshot of the offline maintenance message on Christianity.SE]

Comment: While I've only noticed it on this one site, it's very easy to believe that it's also an issue for other sites. But if it gets closed I can move it to the child meta.

Comment: Turns out this bug is also 3 years old: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5925/6071

Comment: I've seen more issues with text colors on their background, either in full-site view or mobile view on several sites so I have the opinion this question doesn't belong on a specific site. It is just an example of a wider problem. If I find an appropriate duplicate I close vote against that one but for now this has my re-open vote.